# How to install Elixir via CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, centos7

I want to install Elixir v 1.14.3 OTP 25 on my CentOS Server.

I have a link but I don't know which CLI command I have to type in to install this? Sorry I'm a beginner :)

https://repo.hex.pm/builds/elixir/v1.14.3-otp-25.zip

with **yum install elixir** my system installs just a old Version :(

I don't want to use asdf because it's something more to install that I don't know how. There must be a simple way or not?

Answer (score 0):

It was just these commands in the root folder:

```
wget https://repo.hex.pm/builds/elixir/v1.14.3-otp-25.zip
unzip v1.14.3-otp-25.zip
```

Elixir is running now.